No ODAC Driver found when running a macro in Excel
A user was trying to running a macro within an excel sheet, but when doing so, we run into the error of excel saying it's a -1004 runtime error. Upon further digging, we discover that the issue bounces back with a No ODAC driver found issue. Then we looked at the ODAC drivers, and found that on the computers that where the sheet marco's worked, it had the "Oracle in 12.2" (the highlighted yellow) driver installed. However, we cannot seem to find where to install that driver. We are running office 32-bit version as well.
[List of drivers from another working computer] (https://i.sstatic.net/kZpEl5mb.png)
We have tried installing the instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip from Oracle's website, and it doesn't populate that after the installation. It only adds "Oracle in OraClient 12Home1_32bit".

First you need to find out, which driver is used by the macro. See How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net to get an idea.
Then, most likely you mixed up 32-bit and 64-bit drivers. When your MS Office is 32-bit then the Oracle client and driver must also be 32-bit, you cannot mix it. If you like to install both, 32-bit and 64-bit, follow this instruction: Installing Oracle 32-bit Client on Windows Server Already Running 64-bit Oracle Database Server
I suggest to remove any Oracle clients properly from your computer before you start a fresh installation.

The macro runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit office. But I will try from a fresh install.

It does not matter. It depends whether your Excel is 32-bit or 64-bit. The Oracle must be the same.
